# Fix for SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

Tags: python, function, return, syntax-error

I don't know how to solve this error but please help. I have written my code like this.

```
print("i am jarvis please tell me how can i help you...")

inp = input()
print (inp)

with inp as source:
    print(recognising)

try:
    query = webbrowser.open(inp)
    results= (query)
    print(results)

except Execetions as e:
    print("write it again")
    print (e)
    return "none"

return query
```

A very straight forward code and I am getting frustrated with this error

```
C:\Users\good pc\Documents\Jarvis>"C:/Users/good pc/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/python.exe" "c:/Users/good
pc/Documents/Jarvis/jarvisdemo.py"
  File "c:/Users/good pc/Documents/Jarvis/jarvisdemo.py", line 36
    return "none"
    ^
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function
```

Comment: You have no right to use `return` outside of a function.
Define a function and then put your code inside.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  What do you expect `return "none"` to do in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning outside a function, wrap everything to a function and call it:

```
import wikipedia
import datetime
import cv2

hour = int(datetime.datetime.now().hour)

if hour >=0 and hour <=12:
        print("good morning")
elif hour >12 and hour<16:
        print("good afternoon")
elif hour >16 and hour<20:
        print("good evening")
else :
        print("good night")


print("i am jarvis please tell me how can i help you...")

def jar():
inp = input()
print (inp)

with inp as source:
    print(recognising)

def jar():
    inp = input()
    print (inp)

    with inp as source:
        print(recognising)

    try:
        query = webbrowser.open(inp)
        results = query
        print(results)

    except Execption as e:
        print("write it again")
        prin(e)
        return "none"

    return query

print(jar())
```

Comment: `Excecetions` is almost certainly a typo, but fixing it would probably lead to other errors.